# How to fix Smartiest Photo slider indicator not updating after removing slide with ViewAdapter and MVVM architecture in Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewpager, libraries, android-databinding

I am using Smartiest Photo slider library . I have a remove button on each slide , whenever it is clicked that slide is removed. But in my case Slide is removed but the indicator at the bottom remains same. Once screen configuration changes it start working fine. whenever i click remove button, slide is removed and bottom indicator is also decreased. I think problem is with my ViewAdapter but i can't understand where it is.

```
class SliderAdapter  : SliderViewAdapter<SliderAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var images = mutableListOf<Uri>()

    class MyViewHolder ( val binding : SliderItemBinding) : ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(image : Uri){
            binding.sliderImage.setImageURI(image)
        }

        companion object{
            fun from(parent : ViewGroup) : MyViewHolder{
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = SliderItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater , parent , false)
                return MyViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentImage = images[position]
        holder.bind(currentImage)

        // adding removing functionality
        holder.binding.remove.setOnClickListener {
           images.removeAt(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return  images.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder.from(parent!!)
    }

    fun setData(images : List<Uri>){
        this.images = images as MutableList<Uri>
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

I am using MVVM architecture , my mainViewModel has MutableLiveData that holds listOf which i update at mainFragment with the selected images Uris. Then i have databinding Adapter where i set sliderAdapter on the
SliderView.